# Magento 1.9.1 with MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql

The website says the requirement is MySQL 5.6. For some reason my server has to run MySQL 5.5. Will there be any problem to run Magento 1.9.1 on MySQL 5.5? Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: I have `mysql 5.5` with me and `magento 1.9.1` is working just fine in my local machine. So my advice is go on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the [**system requirements for `magento 1.9.1`**](http://magento.com/resources/previous-magento-system-requirements).

It says in short, for `magento Community Edition (CE)`, you need

```
Supported Web Servers
_______________________
    Apache 1.3.x
    Apache 2.0.x
    Apache 2.2.x
    Nginx (starting from Magento 1.7 Community)

PHP Compatibility
_______________________
    PHP 5.4 

MySQL  
_______________________
    MySQL 4.1.20 or later
```

***Please note for Magento Enterprise edition the system requirements are different***

Please go through the link provide and make an idea.

Good luck for your future endeavours

Comment: What I found was something different: [here](http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements). Magento's inconsistent docs sometimes are really confusing.

Comment: wow. That's good. When I get free time, I will check this and let you know the "correct" fact :-) So stay tuned

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for an answer for this myself. We're on a webhost that's still on MySQL 5.1 and I don't know if they're planning to upgrade anytime soon or not.

I had seen the two links previously mentioned in the Magento Resources as well – one, their current main "System Requirements" page, shows **System Requirements for CE 1.9.1** ("MySQL 5.6 required") and the other shows **System Requirements Prior to CE 1.9.1** ("MySQL 4.1.20 or later").

But somehow I stumbled across an article about [Installing Required Prequisite Software for Magento CE 1.8 Magento EE 1.13 (or Later) on Ubuntu](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce-ee-install-ubuntu-prereq#mysql) where it says:

> Magento CE and EE support the following MySQL versions:
>
> - Magento CE 1.9.1 and Magento EE 1.14.1 support MySQL versions 5.0.2 through 5.6.x.
> - Magento CE versions 1.8.0.0–1.9.0.x support MySQL versions 4.1.20–5.5.x.
>
> ...
>
> Only Magento CE 1.9.1 and EE 1.14.1 support MySQL 5.6.

So if that's true, MySQL requirements haven't significantly changed. Magento 1.9.1.0 (or Later) just supports the latest version and dropped 4.x support.

I'll have to test it out before too long. Too many clients will be needing upgrades sooner rather than later.

Comment: I've been running 1.9 with MySQL 5.5 live. No issue so far, but still want to know the truth.

Answer (score 1):

yes...Basically mysql-5.5 is faster then mysql-5.6
If version specified to use mysql-5.6 then the magento 1.9 will give you better performance on mysql-5.6
but you should to use 5.6... it will gives you some new improvement over 5.5...
But mysql-5.6 is slower then 5.5

You will get better compression here ..

[Is MySQL 5.6 slower than MySQL 5.5](http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/02/18/is-mysql-5-6-slower-than-mysql-5-5/)

Answer (score 0):

I compared the code for ce 1.9.1 and 1.9.0.1 with FileMerge.
I'm not seeing any substantial changes. Lots of license updates but not many class updates.

I didn't look at all the differences but I'm 90% sure that this change in docs only reflects an intention to make backwards incompatible changes in the future.

My guess is at this time magento ce 1.9.1 will work just fine with MySQL 5.1 but you're playing with fire. You'll be on your own if you want support from X.commerce and its likely that minor updates will introduce incompatible changes.