# Magento 1.9.2.3 with MySQL 5.5.4

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento-community, server-setup

Does Magento 1.9.2.3 work with MySQL 5.5.4 ?

Comment: Related: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49780/magento-1-9-1-with-mysql-5-5

Answer (score 1):

Out-of-the-box Magento 1.9.2.3 does work with MySQL 5.5.4 
See [System Requirements](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html)

Also, I can confirm from experience that a local copy from a real webshop we maintain here with the agency did work just switching MysQL to 5.5.26 on MampPRO.

However, please do make sure the extensions you have installed are compatible with Magento 1.9.2.3 - a lot of the times we think the problem is Magento, but it is almost every time an extension that is incompatible with either the PHP or MySQL versions or just plain incompatible with Magento version!

Comment: Thanks for replay, but in the System requirement link that you provide the Magento require MySQL 5.6 (Oracle or Percona) ..

Comment: Oops - I think the page did get updated a lot! The best way is to make a copy of your shop on local and try out with MySQL 5.5 before doing it live.