# Magento 1.9.1.1 Compatibility

Tags: php, database, magento-1.9.1.1

Is **Magento 1.9.1.1** compatible with **PHP 7.1** and **MySQL 5.7**? 
And what is the system requirements for Magento 1.9.1.1 ?

Comment: Have a look in to this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49780/magento-1-9-1-with-mysql-5-5

Comment: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/system-requirements.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Magento 1.x is not compatible with php7. The documentation clearly states:

Database

- MySQL 5.6 (Oracle or Percona)

PHP

Magento CE 1.9.2 and later, Magento EE 1.14.2 and later:

- PHP 5.6.x
- PHP 5.4.x
- PHP 5.5.x

Earlier Magento versions:

- PHP 5.4.x
- PHP 5.5.x

See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html

Comment: Why is this answer down-voted? Is it incorrect?

Comment: i dont know, but thanks for the link!

Comment: If the down-voter could reveal themselves and explain I'd be very grateful.

Comment: It is not compatible with 7.x because they DO NOT WANT TO. Thx to that, they can lie about benchmarks 1.x VS 2.x . It's really easy to make it compatible. Just use google and do it, you will gain a lot.